# NFT auction, gas error popping up

Tags: nft

I m trying to build a project where you can auction an NFT. I am using Sepolia Test Network and have enough ETHs in there.

I have 2 main functions that I m using, "start" and "end" functions. Adding bids (bids, addresses) would be done separately through calling. However I ve made addBid function for testings. Here are my codes:

---

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.10;

interface IERC721{
function transfer(address, uint) external;

```
function transferFrom(
    address,
    address,
    uint
) external;
```

}

contract Auction2 {

```
event Start();
event End(address highestBidder, uint highestBid);

address payable public seller;

bool public started;
bool public ended;
uint public endAt;

IERC721 public nft;
uint public nftId;

uint public highestBid;
address public highestBidder;

constructor() {
    seller = payable(msg.sender);
}

function addBid(uint _highestBid, address _highestBidder) public {
    highestBid = _highestBid;
    highestBidder = _highestBidder;
}

function start(IERC721 _nft, uint _nftId, uint startingBid) external {
    require(!started, "Already started!");
    require(msg.sender == seller, "You did not start the auction!");

    highestBid = startingBid;

    nft = _nft;
    nftId = _nftId;
    nft.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), nftId); 

    started = true;
    endAt = block.timestamp + 1 minutes;

    emit Start();
}
    function end() external {
    require(started, "You need to start first!");
    require(block.timestamp >= endAt, "Auction is still ongoing!");
    require(!ended, "Auction already ended!");

    if (highestBidder != address(0)) {
        nft.transferFrom(address(this), highestBidder, nftId);
        (bool sent, ) = seller.call{value: highestBid , gas :20000}("");
        require(sent,"Failed to send ether");
    } else { 
        nft.transfer(seller, nftId);
    }
    
    ended = true;
    emit End(highestBidder, highestBid);
}
```

### }

and the error I am getting is :
User
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted","id":4314845473207436}

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a couple of thing that are wrong.

The person who calls the end() method will already pay the gas for the transfer of the nft so there is no need to provide gas.

The gas you provide is in fact coming from the contract itself which at this point contain a value of highestBid. So you are technically trying to send highestBid+ some gas and you most likely exceed the balance of the contract.